# What Are The Best Width Ranges for Media Queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

What are the best width ranges for detecting media queries in a responsive design?

I would like to cover all Desktop/Laptop monitors( with one orientation) in 4 media queries but I do not know if it is possible for example: small monitors, medium monitors, large and extra large monitors.

For example in this code

```
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
 @media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {}

/* Large screens ----------- */
 @media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {}
```

I think we need still to device the Desktops and laptops media into three sub media as small (like 13" to 14 laptops), medium (like 15 to 17) and large (over 22#). I know that the browser resolution is different than screen resolutions but let's say we have browsers in full-screen mode in all formats.

Answer (score 53):

Try this one with retina display

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

### Update

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPad 3 (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPad 3 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1824px) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 26):

You can take a look [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for a longer list of screen sizes and respective media queries.

Or go for [**Bootstrap media queries (archived)**](https://web.archive.org/web/20121125094111/http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive):

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
 
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }
 
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
 
/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

*Update:*

*[Bootstrap 5 breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#media-queries)*

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1400px
);
```

---

Additionally you might wanty to take a look at [**Foundation's media queries**](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/modules/_mqueries.scss) with the following default settings:

```
// Media Queries

$screenSmall: 768px !default;
$screenMedium: 1279px !default;
$screenXlarge: 1441px !default;
```

*Update:*

*[Foundation 6 breakpoints](https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/6cdc5964a955fa04e3e1b5fbadbdb2fe3c9963a8/scss/settings/_settings.scss#L105)*

```
$breakpoints: (
  small: 0,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
);
```

Answer (score 3):

best bet is targeting features not devices unless you have to, bootstrap do well and you can extend on their breakpoints, for instance targeting pixel density and larger screens above 1920